# Why does webpagetest keep giving error?

Tags: performance, html, webpagetest, web-performance

I want to use webpagetest to measure the performance of webpage by scripting the steps in a file.

But when i run `webpagetest test <url>/<script>`, I get below error:

```
An error occurred processing your request (missing API key).  If you do not have an API key assigned you can request one at http://www.webpagetest.org/getkey.php
```

I have requested an API key and received it to but still getting the error. What am I doing wrong?

Is there anything else I can use to view page/action wise performance of webpage

Comment: Can you post the contents of your file?

Comment: I am not using  a file . I just executed `webpagetest test http://www.google.com`

Comment: Is this the node.js client?  How are you passing your API key in?  Assuming this is the node.js client, you can use the -k option: `webpagetest -k YOUR_KEY test <url>/<script>`

Comment: You're welcome, I've put it as an answer instead.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is the node.js client, you can use the -k option:

```
webpagetest -k YOUR_KEY test <url>/<script>
```